# Best practice to async play separate MIDI messages?

Tags: delphi, pascal, midi, lazarus

I've parsed a MIDI file into an array of notes (key, velocity, time, also the MIDI file's tempo and its change events). I need to play them back asynchronous of a GUI (LCL) app (I can't use `MCISendString`, because I need to process those messages). The thing is, in MIDIs there are normally thousands of notes. What do you think would be the best way to play them back?

I've got some ideas, but they're slow and impractical:

- Call a bunch of `BeginThread`s at once with a function that waits (`Sleep` or `Delay`) for the specified amount of time and plays the note (there's a limit on threads and it's really unstable).
- Sorting the timestamps and then running them through a single thread that will Sleep/Delay the `currentNoteTime-previousNoteTime` and play the note. Might be slow, especially when trying to sort all of it.
- Write another app to be a background process and do the job (unprofessional bodging).

I'm working with Lazarus (Object Pascal), but I can utilize Delphi code too if needed. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All threading approaches (sleep, delay, etc) will fail on Windows since you won't get accuracy better than 16ms (in best case) which will cause your data is played back incorrectly, with big latency. It's known problem, you can search for it on the web.

I'm author of [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) C# library which has playback functionality. My approach is:

1. Sort all events by time and set pointer to start of MIDI data
2. Run high-precision timer using [Windows Multimedia Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timers) API which will tick every 1ms
3. On each tick see what events should be played by the current time and send those events to output device
4. Move pointer forward by played events

But please note that this approach works for Windows only. For other systems you need to use OS specific API to run high-precision timers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it out and try your approach. Btw, used your library in the past for some personal projects. Great stuff!

Comment: Thanks :) You can start your investigation from DWM playback's `OnClockTicked` method: https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/blob/develop/DryWetMidi/Devices/Playback/Playback.cs#L696

Comment: Worked like a charm, even when there were semi-heavy performance load things happening in the background. Now all that's left is to sort the stuff, which I think will be easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Maxim There are several high precision timer components available for Delphi. Some even allow changing delay interval during execution so instead of need to check if there are certain event schedulet fat current timer interval you can simply jump to next event. Such timers are often used in game development especially when dealing with physics simulation etc.

Comment: @SilverWarior Can you name those components? Do they use [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) hardware timer like WinMM does?

Comment: There are so many and it has been some time since I used one. At the time I was still using Delphi 7.